# Where in a Seam bean do I direct the code to my database table?

Tags: java, postgresql, jsf, seam

I'm new to seam framework and I'm wondering if I have a xhtml page and a bean, where is the line that tells the bean the name of my database table and the command on what it needs to add or delete from the table?

I have already set up my seam project and told it my database username and password with seam-gen.

Not sure if this makes a difference but its postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a separate entity bean (normally 1 per table), if you are using JPA then this is a class marked with the @Entity annotation and references the database table using the @Table annotation

Nb. If you already have a database or schema you can use Hibernate Tools to automatically generate these entities for you including all the mappings for each column

See the seam docs here:

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.3.1.Final/reference/html_single/#d0e3758

And an example JPA entity bean:

```
@Entity

@Name("user")

@Scope(SESSION)

@Table(name="users")

public class User implements Serializable

{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1881413500711441951L;



   private String username;

   private String password;

   private String name;



   public User(String name, String password, String username)

   {

      this.name = name;

      this.password = password;

      this.username = username;

   }



   public User() {}



   @NotNull @Size(min=5, max=15)

   public String getPassword()

   {

      return password;

   }


   public void setPassword(String password)

   {

      this.password = password;

   }



   @NotNull

   public String getName()

   {

      return name;

   }


   public void setName(String name)

   {

      this.name = name;

   }



   @Id @NotNull @Size(min=5, max=15)

   public String getUsername()

   {

      return username;

   }


   public void setUsername(String username)

   {

      this.username = username;

   }


}
```